# istream_iterator read values from file into set

Tags: c++, set, ifstream

I am having difficulty using the istream_iterator for the purpose I need. I have a file that I want to read line by line into a set. I have to use the iterator and I was wondering if there's something wrong with my code or my approach.

The help is much appreciated. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm writing:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream file("fruits.txt");

    set<string> M;

    copy(istream_iterator<string>(file),
         istream_iterator<string>(),
         [](string & s){ M.insert(s); });

    for( auto val : M ) {
        cout << val << ", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

fruits.txt

```
banana
apple
pear
strawberry
blueberry
peach
pear
apple
```

Errors:

```
main.cpp:16:26: Variable 'M' cannot be implicitly
captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified


/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr
/include/c++/v1/algorithm:1750:49: Cannot increment value of type '(lambda at 
/Users/cnapoli22/Downloads/TEST SHIT/TEST SHIT/main.cpp:16:10)'
```

Comment: You should provide the error you are getting when you ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last argument to `copy` needs to be an iterator, not a lambda:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("fruits.txt");

    set<string> M;

    copy(istream_iterator<string>(file),
         istream_iterator<string>(),
         inserter(M, M.end()));

    for (auto const& val : M)
    {
        cout << val << ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: It compiles fine now, but M remains empty? fruits.txt is in the right directory, but could it be a problem with my build settings or something?

Comment: @Cameron oops sorry. Change `std::cin` to `file`. See edit.

Comment: Okay. Still not working. This may be an issue with my IDE (using Xcode). Is it outputting correctly on your computer?

Comment: @Cameron works on mine. I tested using `cin` though not `file`, which is why that typo slipped in. I just tested using a file on VS2015 and it works also.

Comment: Hmm will look into this. Thanks for the help!